# Export to TAB with styling using ogr2ogr

Tags: mapinfo, ogr2ogr, tab

We have a lot of our data stored in a PostGIS database and I need to create some styled MapInfo TAB file. So I have added an MI_STYLE column (varchar254) that contains a simple brush fill

`BRUSH(fc:#0000FF);PEN(c:#000000)`

I then export to TAB using ogr2ogr and open in MapInfo and I see polygons with the default black line but it should be a blue polygon with a black line.

Having read this [similar question](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/ogr2ogr-MapInfo-Tab-Styling-td3751530.html) it seems I should be using OGR_STYLE as I am doing styling per row. So I changed my PostGIS database column name and did the export again. Unfortunately I still get the same result as above.

Can anyone help with an example?

What column name is MapInfo expecting?

And what is the correct ogr2ogr export?

Answer (score 1):

It should work as you did with the OGR_STYLE field but I do not have MapInfo available for testing. Here is one polygon in OpenJUMP JML format.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<JCSDataFile xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance" >
<JCSGMLInputTemplate>
<CollectionElement>featureCollection</CollectionElement>
<FeatureElement>feature</FeatureElement>
<GeometryElement>geometry</GeometryElement>
<CRSElement>boundedBy</CRSElement>
<ColumnDefinitions>
     <column>
          <name>OGR_STYLE</name>
          <type>STRING</type>
          <valueElement elementName="property" attributeName="name" attributeValue="OGR_STYLE"/>
          <valueLocation position="body"/>
     </column>
</ColumnDefinitions>
</JCSGMLInputTemplate>

<featureCollection>
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Box>
      <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">-156156.64,7229908.00 185812.64,7521587.68</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Box>
  </gml:boundedBy>
  <feature>
    <geometry>
      <gml:Polygon>
        <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
        <gml:LinearRing>
          <gml:coordinates>
            -156156.64000000007,7504824.48 
            185812.63999999996,7521587.68 
            16504.31999999993,7229908.0 
            -156156.64000000007,7504824.48 
          </gml:coordinates>
        </gml:LinearRing>
        </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
      </gml:Polygon>
    </geometry>
    <property name="OGR_STYLE">BRUSH(fc:#0000FF);PEN(c:#000000)</property>
  </feature>
</featureCollection>
</JCSDataFile>
```

Ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo mi_styletest.jml -al
INFO: Open of `mi_styletest.jml'
      using driver `JML' successful.

Layer name: mi_styletest
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 1
Extent: (-156156.640000, 7229908.000000) - (185812.640000, 7521587.680000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
OGR_STYLE: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(mi_styletest):0
  OGR_STYLE (String) = BRUSH(fc:#0000FF);PEN(c:#000000)
  Style = BRUSH(fc:#0000FF);PEN(c:#000000)
  POLYGON ((-156156.64 7504824.48,185812.64 7521587.68,16504.32 7229908.0,-156156.64 7504824.48))
```

Conversion into MapInfo MID/MIF:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MapInfo file" mi_styletest.mif mi_styletest.jml
```

Now ogrinfo finds these styled from the mif:

```
  Style = BRUSH(fc:#0000ff,id:"mapinfo-brush-1,ogr-brush-1");PEN(w:1px,c:#000000,id:"mapinfo-pen-2,ogr-pen-0")
```

I do not know the MID/MIF format but the styles seem to be converted into the mif part this way:

```
Pen (1,2,0)
Brush (1,255)
```

Copy-paste and save the JML into a file, run the ogr2ogr command and try how MapInfo shows the MID/MIF data.

**EDIT**

By the document https://web.archive.org/web/20060909054240/http://resource.mapinfo.com/static/files/document/1074660800077/interchange_file.pdf the Brush does not get converted right.

> Pattern number 1 is “no fill,” and pattern number 2 is a solid fill

Edit the MIF file to use `Brush (2,255)` and see again if you can get your blue fill. If you can consider to create a GDAL issue into https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal.